# How i can use min-height with 'float:left'?

Tags: margin, css

I have really simple web page.

My css cod :

```
#bodyPart {
clear : both;
width : 1100px;
min-height : 500px;
margin-top : 10px;
margin-left : auto;
margin-right : auto;
border-style : solid;
border-width : 0px 1px;
border-color : white;
}

#left {
float : left;
width : 790px;
margin-left : 10px;
background-color : green;
}

#right {
float : left;
width : 280px;
margin-left : 10px;
background-color : darkgreen;
}
```

Html :

```
<div id ="bodyPart">
    <div id ="left"></div>
    <div id ="right"></div> 
</div>
```

The min-height property does not include padding, borders, or margins!
But how i can make longer "bodyPart" when "left" is being longer :S :S
Is there any solution for this :S

Comment: :S:S:S:S:S:S:S:S:S:S:S:S:S:S:S:S:S:S:S:S:S:S:S:S:S:S:S:S:S:S:S:S:S

Comment: Is there a way we can know which div is in which div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make the `height` of `#bodyPart` to `auto` along with the `min-height`

```
#bodyPart {
clear : both;
width : 1100px;
min-height : 500px;
margin-top : 10px;
margin-left : auto;
margin-right : auto;
border-style : solid;
border-width : 0px 1px;
border-color : white;
height:auto;
}
```

and then add a div to clear

HTML

```
 <div id ="bodyPart">
    <div id ="left"></div>
    <div id ="right"></div> 
    <div class="clear"></div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
.clear {clear:both;}
```

Comment: Sorry, i writed wrongly. I wanted to ask 
"How i can use min-height with 'float:left'?"
But, whatever your solition is working perfectly. Thank you very much.. 

+1 +1 +1

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `min-height` has nothing to do with the padding or margins or borders, secondly you can make each element longer (in height of course,) when its parent's size increases.

For that you must be using percentage heights. Lets say this:

```
div {
  min-height: 90%;
}
```

This way, this div will fill the `90%` of the parent (in this case `body` if there is no other container).

Also, I cannot understand what the divs relate to each other. So its hard to judge. But you can use percentage to fill the parent div's space. This way, when the browser will resize the element will resize and will fill the space.

I am guessing that in your case, `left` is a child and `bodyPart` is parent (meaning that left is inside the parent). For this you would require JS to get the height of the child and then set the height for the parent. If there is some sort of scrolls in your code, then remove them and the parent will definitely get more height when the child will get some!

```
div {
 overflow-x: none; // for the parent
}
```

Tell me more :) So I can help you out.